# How to make an Openlayers map based on geojson layers with exposed filters?

Tags: views, 8, javascript

Openlayers builds maps combining multiple layers, some of which are based off of view into a single map. From what I have experimented with, putting an exposed filter on a geojson based views, doesn't put an exposed filter on top of the map block. So, how could I make a map that would be searchable through an exposed filter?

Comment: Have you considered using https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc for this? Have a look at the "View and maps" part on its project page, I'm not sure I 100% understand our question, but it seems that using this module might help, no?

Comment: I'll have to take a deeper look at the functionality to see if it can be adapted to my use case, but I'm not sure that it will work. What it comes down to, is that what is loaded into the page as an OL map isn't a view the way that a Gmap map is. OL creates the map object through JS and uses views geojson feeds as sources for the individual layers. From what I've tinkered around with if you stick an exposed filter on an OL map with OL-7-3.x it doesn't get included in the map display.